# Any tool that can upgrade .NET 1.1 WinForm code to .NET 2.0 "style"?

Tags: winforms, upgrade

I mean a tool that can extract certain contents from old .NET 1.1 WinForm code and put it in .designer file (make it looks like .net 2.0 WinForm code). This also involves an update to the project file (.csproj/.vbproj)..

If no existing tool yet, any tip or pointer on how to do this by programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do using a macro, have a look at [this article](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/jamesnies/archive/2006/11/27/VS2005DesignerClassMacroForCSharp.aspx) for the macro code.

If anyone else is looking to do this for VB.net (as I did) the only example I could find was this one in c# but it gave me a basis and we got it to work with a vb project.

Comment: Thanks for your info. BUt I've tried the marco, it seems not work for me (error msg box pops up), any trick here?
btw: the sentence "The macro expects the code view for the class to split to be the active VS document" means to open the XXForm.cs file in VS, right?

Comment: I believe so as the macro is looking for the active document. I could not find my vb code as I used this sometime ago and no longer have any old c# code to test this on. Sorry.